# Does the browser retry TLS handshake if it fails the first one?

Tags: ssl, handshake

If a web server fails to complete TLS handshake and returns error to TLS client (i.e. browser), does a typical TLS client such as chrome browser retry the handshake a few times before giving up? And if it does retry how many retries? Also is there a TLS handshake timeout in chrome, past that would it retry or just give up ?

Comment: No. Why would they do that? What would change to make it succeed the second time?

Answer (score 0):

In the past browsers tried the TLS handshake itself with an older TLS version in the hope that it will succeed then. Today browsers usually don't do this anymore, i.e. if the initial connection fails they don't retry.

> Also is there a TLS handshake timeout in chrome

There is one, i.e. the browser will not wait forever for the server to reply but give up after a while.

Comment: Really? Why? Until recently you could send an SSLv2ClientHello and get any TLS/SSL version from 3.0 to 3.x, whateve X was. No need for a second handshake.

Comment: @user207421: There is no TLS/SSL 3.x with x>0.  There is SSL 3.0 and then TLS 1.0 ... 1.3. Apart from that this downgrade with done to deal with broken servers which simply failed when confronted with a TLS 1.2 request instead of replying with the best they can (i.e. like TLS 1.0) as expected by the standard.